# jQuery : Passing Variable Value From On Click Event Failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript :

```
<?
var dropzone_maxfiles = '.$product_maxfiles.';

$( ".product_imgfiles" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var img_file = $( this ).children( "img" ).attr( "src" );

    $.ajax({
        url: "controller/ctrl.dropzonejs-cleaner.php?token='.$product_token.'&key='.$secret_token.'&imgfile="+img_file+""
    });

    $( this ).parent( "div" ).remove();                 
    dropzone_maxfiles = dropzone_maxfiles + 1;
});

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
    url: "controller/ctrl.dropzonejs.php?token='.$product_token.'&key='.$secret_token.'",
    maxFilesize: 2,
    maxFiles: dropzone_maxfiles,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif"
});

myDropzone.on("complete", function() {
    var rejected = myDropzone.getRejectedFiles();

    if (rejected == "" ) {
        $(".btn-vendor-addnew").removeClass("disabled");
        $(".dropzone-error").css("display","none");
    }else {
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
        $(".btn-vendor-addnew").addClass("disabled");
        $(".dropzone-error").css("display","block");

        $.ajax({
            url: "controller/ctrl.dropzonejs-cleaner.php?token='.$product_token.'&key='.$secret_token.'"
        });
    }
});
?>
```

the problem is : `dropzone_maxfiles = dropzone_maxfiles + 1;` value doesn't exist in `maxFiles: dropzone_maxfiles,`

how to pass that `dropzone_maxfiles` variable from on click event into Dropzone `maxFiles`? thank you.

Comment: Why is your JS encapsulated in `<?php` (PHP) `?>` tags?

Comment: There also shouldn't be a trailing comma after the line `maxFiles: dropzone_maxfiles`

Comment: what you see is short version of the real case. I need PHP to get `$product_maxfiles` from PHP

Comment: @JonathanLam : actually there are more lines inside myDropzone. I just make it short and focus on the problem

Comment: Can you show your `Dropzone()` constructor?

Comment: Primitive values are not copied by "reference", so updating the variable at a later time doesn't update the object passed to the function, which is probably already consumed somehow by `new Dropzone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @adeneo said in the comments, the property `maxFiles` of the `Dropzone` object will not change automatically if the variable is changed.

Instead, try reinitializing it with the current variable on click, or perhaps just change that property value (I'm not sure exactly how `Dropzone` is implemented, so there might be some setter method to do this for you).

---

**EDIT** (upon request): a basic example:

```
$( ".product_imgfiles" ).click(function(event) {
    // ... event handling code          
    dropzone_maxfiles = dropzone_maxfiles + 1;

    // add this to "reset" the Dropzone
    myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
        url: "controller/ctrl.dropzonejs.php?token='.$product_token.'&key='.$secret_token.'",
        maxFilesize: 2,
        maxFiles: dropzone_maxfiles,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif"
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi bro, I just updated my full code because I'm not sure which one is  the constructor and setter. I'm still new in this jQuery world. usually in PHP, when the variable updated, then the rest of the code will get updated value as well. but not in jQuery. any idea how to solve this situation? thank you.

Comment: @RobertHanson Ok, I'll provide the simplest example: to simply "reset" the variable with the updated value. Tell me if it works.

Comment: bro, logically what you do is pretty make sense... but after I implement your code, the `dropzone` still read `var myDropzone` which generated by    `$(document).ready(function(){`. this is really strange... why this reset trick is not working?

Comment: @RobertHanson Silly me! Sorry, you don't need the `var` in the declaration -- this creates a local variable (so it update the global one).